# Windows sidebar click event does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, windows-desktop-gadgets

I use a click event in jQuery in my windows sidebar project that doesn't work in the sidebar (i don't think it's binded), but it works on a browser (even IE7). Here is a simple example from my project that doesn't work in my sidebar, and I hope somebody can tell me why, because I couldn't figure it out.

```
<html>
    <head>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                $('#clickable_div').click(function(){
                    $('#textContent').append($('<h4 />').text('change'));
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body style="width: 200px; height: 250px; border: 1px solid black;">
        <div id="clickable_div" style="width: 50px; height: 50px;border:1px solid black;">Click the div</div>
        <div id="textContent"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is jQuery even available? I am not sure if youre allowed to load external libs in a gadget that way.

Comment: Yes, jQuery is available. I'm using in my project a jQuery plugin

Comment: And your click events usually work? I could think of a scoping problem. Have you tried non-static positioning in combination with z-index? You can check if your event is bound by hacking this little sweety into your code -> http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event+2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem, even if I don't know why it does not work with jQuery's click method.

I used javascript's onclick, and it's working now.